# How to predict some constant number of values with NeuralNetworks

Tags: graphs-and-networks, fitting, commercial-package, neural-networks

Example:

```
<< NeuralNetworks`
data = {Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 4 Pi, 0.5];
learn = data[[1 ;; 15]];
```

Now, lets fit our neural network:

```
{model1, fitrecord} = NeuralARFit[learn, 3, FeedForwardNet, {}, 0, CriterionPlot -> False]
p = NetPredict[learn, model1, PredictHorizon -> 1]
ListLinePlot[Flatten[learn~Join~p]] (* Plot it! *)
```

In the result the `Length@p == Length@learn == 15`. Is it true, that we predict 15 values? How can you predict only 1 or 2 or 3 values (e.g. `p[[1]], p[[1;;2]], p[[1;;3]]`) or an arbitrary `n` values?

Is it right the idea to use `NeuralARXFit[d1,d2,...]` and `Dimensions@First@d2 = {N,3}` if we want to predict only 3 values ?